# CIBERSORT runtime error

Tags: webservice, cibersort

I was running [CIBERSORT](https://cibersort.stanford.edu) web and saw this error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at launch.QN.doQN(QN.java:56)
at launch.Cibersort.Run_CIBERSORT(Cibersort.java:611)
at launch.Cibersort.run_all(Cibersort.java:179)
at launch.Cibersort$runCIBERSORT.run(Cibersort.java:1585)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
311
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the bug. CIBERSORT seems to require tsv files instead of csv files. Plus it doesn't seem to like empty columns